# I have a custom table in my craft plugin at the backend and I have to include custom sorting on each field of the table using javascript

Tags: craft3, plugin-development, javascript

The Table includes this field:

Name
            Age
            City
            State

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the below steps.

**Use a sorting class for each field.**

```
<table class="data">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="sorting" >Name</th>
            <th class="sorting">Age</th>
            <th class="sorting">City</th>
            <th class="sorting">State</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

**Then include this script:**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("th.sorting").each(function(){
                var th_obj = $(this);
                
       th_obj.removeClass('ordered').removeClass('asc').removeClass('desc');
                var a_class = th_obj.find('a').attr("class");
                if(a_class != '' && a_class != undefined) {
                    th_obj.addClass('ordered').addClass(a_class);
                }
            });
        }, 100);
    });
</script>
```

**Also Include CSS for sorting class: (You can change this according to your use and theme)**

```
table.data thead th.ordered:not(.loading):after {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    font-size: 0;
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    border: solid #596673;
    border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
    position: absolute;
}
table.data thead th.ordered {
   background-color:unset;
}
body.ltr table.data thead th.ordered:not(.desc):after {
    top: calc(50% - 1px);
}
body.ltr table.data thead th.ordered.desc:after {
     top: calc(50% - 4px);
}
```

I hope this will work for you.

Thanks.